# android MediaPlayer not playing mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player

I have written the most basic application I can think of to try to play an mp3 file, but it is not working.  I don't get any errors, but when the application starts up, the sound is not played.

```
public class soundtest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.norm_iphone_money);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  I have "norm_iphone_money.mp3" inside the res/raw folder.  The file plays fine in Windows Media Player and iTunes.

I'm using the latest versions of Java SDK and Eclipse for Java.  The app is targeted for Android 2.2 and runs fine in the emulator despite no sound.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?
 
You might try using the setDataSource() and prepare() methods before a MediaPlayer start() instead of create(), but I doubt that will work if create() doesn't...

Answer (score 44):

The problem is that the media volume is set to 0 (not the ringer volume). You can set it by:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Have a look at the [developer page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654620/what-do-the-the-flag-parameter-means-and-range-of-possible-min-and-max-of-droid) for the explanation of parameters for setStreamVolume(int, int, int).

Comment: what is this StartUpActivity

Comment: edited the answer! StartupActivity is just an Activity in my project. But we can refer the constant AUDIO_SERVICE by Context class. Activity is just a Context, and AUDIO_SERVICE is a static constant string of Context. Thanks a lot for your feedback, Deppzz!

Comment: And there goes an hour of my life... Thanks !!

Comment: @XuanTungVu  .. Please explain about these values   20 and 0 in (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0)..

Comment: Thanks, added links to the explanation.

Comment: This works but why? I mean, my code has been working for months and suddenly sound went out without error.. may be an android update?

Answer (score 10):

Try replacing these two lines:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.norm_iphone_money);
```

with this one line:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.norm_iphone_money);
```

And see if that works.

Comment: if these two are writings are any logically different whatsoever in the compiled code, I'd be shocked.

Comment: No but testing it myself it only works that way, it doesn't work how he originally wrote it. If anyone else cares to explain exactly *why* that is, that would be great. Playing a RAW audio resource is described right here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: Of course it is logically different. mp.create will call the static method, and it will return a new instance of a MediaPlayer, which is never stored. Then, he calls start() on the default-constructed instance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with emulator, change the emulator or try to run the application on a real device. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

The static method create(Context, int) from the type MediaPlayer should be accessed in a static way. Try this:

```
MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.norm_iphone_money).start();
```

It will play the .mp3 with this line too

```
mp.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.norm_iphone_money).start();
```

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest this :

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
//bla bla bla
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.norm_iphone_money);
```

Comment: Why do yo create a media player `mp`, then replace it with the output from `MediaPlayer.create`?

Answer (score -4):

Had the same problem
after i clicked to start the Media Player, the screen went black and the app stopped.

i just changed

> MediaPlayer mp = MediaPLayer.create(this,R.raw.sound);    mp.start();

to

> MediaPlayer mp = MediaPLayer.create(this,R.raw.sound).start();

I am not really sure what is the difference there, but it solved my problem.

Comment: There is no difference if you just chain the method call.