# What does the flag parameter mean and what is range of possible min and max of droid device

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager

1. I want to know what is flag(or what are the possible values for
   flag)  in

   **audiomanager.setStreamVolume (int streamType, int index, int flags);**
2. I know we can get the maximum stream using

   **audiomanger.getMaxStream(audioManager.getStreamMax(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));**

But in some device it gives 13,15, it depends on Android version or device hardware and what is it range(minimum possible value, maximum possible value)

Sets the volume index for a particular stream.

This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed().// what does it mean.

**Parameters**

```
streamType  The stream whose volume index should be set.

index   The volume index to set. See getStreamMaxVolume(int) for the largest valid value.

flags   One or more flags. // what are these flags
```

Answer (score 19):

**About the flag parameter**: 
There are some flags defined in *AudioManager.java*.
You can use any one of them to get the desired affect.
example :

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

or simply

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,1);
```

here is the code segment from *AudioManager.java* showing how they are defined.

```
public static final int FLAG_SHOW_UI = 1 << 0;

/**
 * Whether to include ringer modes as possible options when changing volume.
 * For example, if true and volume level is 0 and the volume is adjusted
 * with {@link #ADJUST_LOWER}, then the ringer mode may switch the silent or
 * vibrate mode.
 * <p>
 * By default this is on for the ring stream. If this flag is included,
 * this behavior will be present regardless of the stream type being
 * affected by the ringer mode.
 *
 * @see #adjustVolume(int, int)
 * @see #adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int)
 */
public static final int FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES = 1 << 1;

/**
 * Whether to play a sound when changing the volume.
 * <p>
 * If this is given to {@link #adjustVolume(int, int)} or
 * {@link #adjustSuggestedStreamVolume(int, int, int)}, it may be ignored
 * in some cases (for example, the decided stream type is not
 * {@link AudioManager#STREAM_RING}, or the volume is being adjusted
 * downward).
 *
 * @see #adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int)
 * @see #adjustVolume(int, int)
 * @see #setStreamVolume(int, int, int)
 */
public static final int FLAG_PLAY_SOUND = 1 << 2;

/**
 * Removes any sounds/vibrate that may be in the queue, or are playing (related to
 * changing volume).
 */
public static final int FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE = 1 << 3;

/**
 * Whether to vibrate if going into the vibrate ringer mode.
 */
public static final int FLAG_VIBRATE = 1 << 4;

/**
 * Indicates to VolumePanel that the volume slider should be disabled as user
 * cannot change the stream volume
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_FIXED_VOLUME = 1 << 5;

/**
 * Indicates the volume set/adjust call is for Bluetooth absolute volume
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_BLUETOOTH_ABS_VOLUME = 1 << 6;

/**
 * Adjusting the volume was prevented due to silent mode, display a hint in the UI.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_SHOW_SILENT_HINT = 1 << 7;

/**
 * Indicates the volume call is for Hdmi Cec system audio volume
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_HDMI_SYSTEM_AUDIO_VOLUME = 1 << 8;

/**
 * Indicates that this should only be handled if media is actively playing.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVE_MEDIA_ONLY = 1 << 9;

/**
 * Like FLAG_SHOW_UI, but only dialog warnings and confirmations, no sliders.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_SHOW_UI_WARNINGS = 1 << 10;

/**
 * Adjusting the volume down from vibrated was prevented, display a hint in the UI.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_SHOW_VIBRATE_HINT = 1 << 11;

/**
 * Adjusting the volume due to a hardware key press.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int FLAG_FROM_KEY = 1 << 12;
```